# Assembly highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly, masm

I am using visual stduio 2010, I am installing the [ASM highlighting](http://asmhighlighter.codeplex.com/releases/view/57864) but I get this message every time.

> this extension is not intallable on any currently installed program.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio edition?

Comment: Visual studio 2010 Express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio Express doesn't support extensions (including AsmHighlighter). You need at least Visual Studio Professional to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... I downloaded ultimate one and it works fine.